# WSL PATH command help

Tags: linux, windows

Following these intr: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-windows.md I have retrieved a git for a crypto. But I am hung up on the step where I add the PATH command. Per the instr:

```
PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:\/mnt.*//g') # strip out problematic Windows %PATH% imported var.
```

I am unsure of what to place in this command. But obviously need to put a correct file location for my git? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is a command that you enter into the command prompt. This isn't a file or something that you have to add to a file, just type it (or copy and paste it) into the command prompt once the bash shell is running.